# Append GET parameter to php URL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a form that populates a database containing customer data. What i'd like to do is that when `isset($_POST["submit"])`, a GET parameter is appended to the URL, like `&customer=<?php echo $last_id ?>` where `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);`

Is this possible? Would this be a true GET parameter inserted in the GET array? Is also possible to populate the form with this newly added parameter?

Thank you very much!

This is the code, simplified

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) {
$nome_paciente = mysql_pre($_POST["nome"]);

$query  = "INSERT INTO pacientes (";
$query .= "id, nome";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= "$id, \"{$nome_paciente}\"
$query .= ")";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>

<form action="cadastro_paciente.php?subject=1&paciente=<?php echo $_POST["id"]; ?>" method="post" class="form-cadastro">


<div class="first-value">
<p class="opensans">Nome: </p>
<input type="text" class="table-nome" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome ?>">
</div>

<input type="text" class="id" name="id" style="display:none" value="$_GET['id']">

<?php } else { ?>

<form action="cadastro_paciente.php?subject=1&paciente=<?php echo $_POST["id"]; ?>" method="post" class="form-cadastro">


<div class="first-value">
<p class="opensans">Nome: </p>
<input type="text" class="table-nome" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome ?>">
</div>

<input type="text" class="id" name="id" style="display:none" value="$_GET['id']"> 
?php } ?>
```

but i keep getting in my url:

```
&paciente=<br%20/><b>Notice</b>:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20id%20in%20<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\...
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? POST to a page with a variable in the GET parameter? You can just POST directly to the page itself... `form action="/action_page.php?varible=value"`.

Comment: Thanks Obsidian! So, I understood i can submit it and it would process it anyway, thank you. How do I get to submit with the newly created customer id? I tried with `action="form_action.php?subject=1&customer=<?php echo $_POST["id"]; ?>"` but with no success, there is no field with the id value

Comment: You would need to POST a GET parameter. Confusing I know, but it would look like: `action="form_action.php?subject=1&customer=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>"`. That's assuming `id` is already set. If it's being created **as the form is being submitted**, you would simply pass it through as a (possibly hidden) input field on the form itself :)

Comment: the ID is auto increment, should i just create an hidden field and leave it blank? Also, then would be `=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>` or `=<?php echo $_POST["id"]; ?>`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: By a hidden field, I mean you would need to use an input field on the form, say `name='hidden'`. You would need to populate the field's `value` with `$_GET["id"]`. You could then extract the ID once the form is submitted with `$_POST["hidden"]`, and work with it from there :) For any further help, you'll probably need to post the code you're using :)

Comment: I'm gonna post the code as an answer, i am not doing it right, if you could help i would appreciate a lot! :D

Comment: Please update your **question** to include the code; do not post it as an answer, as it will likely get downvoted and deleted, causing you to lose rep.

Comment: Thanks Obsidian, for the help and for the tip. I will do as you suggested